# ¿Cómo reaccionar en canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Según este código, ¿cómo puedo llamar a una función dependiendo del texto del canvas clicado? En otras palabras, si se hace clic el `Texto 1` , se ejecutará la `funcion 1` y si se hace clic el segundo texto, se ejecutará otra función.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var d = c.getContext("2d");
var divc = document.getElementById("cr");

divc.addEventListener("click", function () {

    var newCanvas = new Sm();

    newCanvas.draw1();
    newCanvas.draw2();

});

function Sm () {

    this.selected = "";

}

Sm.prototype = {

    draw1: function () {

        d.font = "20px Ubuntu";
        d.fillText("Texto 1", 50, 100);

    },
    draw2: function () {

        d.font = "20px Georgia";
        d.fillText("Texto 2", 200, 100);

    }

};
```

```html
<body style="background-color: grey;">
    <input id="cr" type="button" value="Crear canvas"/>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Debes analizar bien si necesitas obligatoriamente `canvas` para tu proyecto. Dependiendo de tu gráfico podrías usar [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial) y podrías añadir interactividad de una manera más sencilla.

En primer lugar debes entender qué cosa es un [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial). Un `canvas` es un elemento en el que representas gráficos y textos pero en modo `bitmap`. Un `canvas` es como una imagen a la que le puedes variar sus pixeles usando para ello `JavaScript`. Por lo tanto, cualquier elemento que dibujes en el canvas no será interactivo. Si quisieras simular que tus elementos son interactivos, deberías capturar un evento `click` sobre el `canvas`, analizar las coordenadas del evento y dependiendo de estas ejecutar una función o la otra, [puedes encontrar varios tutoriales](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/) en internet para implementar esto. Sería algo como el siguiente `snippet`:

> He variado un poco el código para que fuera más dinámico enviando el `canvas` y las coordenadas al constructor. No tienes que hacerlo obligatoriamente así.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var divc = document.getElementById("cr");

divc.addEventListener("click", function () {

  var newCanvas = new Sm(c, {x: 50, y: 100}, {x: 200, y: 100});

  newCanvas.draw1();
  newCanvas.draw2();

});

function Sm (canvas, coords1, coords2) {

  var _scope = this;
  
  this._canvas = canvas;
  this._context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  this._coords1 = coords1 || {x: 0, y: 0};
  this._coords2 = coords2 || {x: 0, y: 0};
  
  this._canvas.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
  
      var cOffset = this.getBoundingClientRect();
      var pageX = evt.pageX - cOffset.left;
      var pageY = evt.pageY - cOffset.top;
      
      if (pageX >= coords1.x && pageX < coords2.x && pageY <= coords1.y && pageY > coords1.y - 20) {
        alert("Teto 1 clicado");
      }
      
      if (pageX >= coords2.x && pageX < coords2.x + 100 && pageY <= coords2.y && pageY > coords2.y - 20) {
        alert("Teto 2 clicado");
      }
  
  });

}

Sm.prototype = {

  draw1: function() {

    this._context.font = "20px Ubuntu";
    this._context.fillText("Texto 1", this._coords1.x, this._coords1.y);

  },
  draw2: function() {

    this._context.font = "20px Georgia";
    this._context.fillText("Texto 2", this._coords2.x, this._coords2.y);

  }

};
```

```html
<body style="background-color: grey;">
  <input id="cr" type="button" value="Crear canvas" />
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Notarás que este método es inexacto y complicado de implementar. Si quieres añadir interactividad a un `canvas` te recomiendo [EaseLJS](http://www.createjs.com/easeljs). Todo sería tan fácil de implementar como el siguiente snippet:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var divc = document.getElementById("cr");

divc.addEventListener("click", function() {

  var newCanvas = new Sm(c, {x: 50, y: 100}, {x: 200, y: 100});

  newCanvas.draw1();
  newCanvas.draw2();
  newCanvas.update();

});

function Sm(canvas, coords1, coords2) {

  var _scope = this;

  this._canvas = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
  this._coords1 = coords1 || {x: 0, y: 0};
  this._coords2 = coords2 || {x: 0, y: 0};

}

Sm.prototype = {

  draw1: function() {

    var text = new createjs.Text("Texto 1", "20px Ubuntu", "#000");
    text.set(this._coords1);    
    this._canvas.addChild(text);
    
    text.addEventListener("click", function () {
      alert("Texto 1 clicado");
    });

  },
  draw2: function() {

    var text = new createjs.Text("Texto 2", "20px Georgia", "#000");
    text.set(this._coords2);    
    this._canvas.addChild(text);
    
    text.addEventListener("click", function () {
      alert("Texto 2 clicado");
    });

  },
  update: function () {
    this._canvas.update();
  }

};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>

<body style="background-color: grey;">
  <input id="cr" type="button" value="Crear canvas" />
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Funciona esa libreria, si el texto cambiara de posición tldo el tiempo?

Comment: Claro que funcionaría, porque variarían las coordenadas del objeto y estas son las que se utilizan para determinar si estás haciendo clic en el mismo. Ten en cuenta que si al cambiar las coordenadas del objeto este queda detrás de uno más grande, no podrías hacer clic en él en ese momento.

Comment: Investigaré sobre el tema, gracias

Comment: De nada, un saludo ;)